# What do the sand people do with Anakin's mother?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Why did they kidnap her (and keep her alive)? Do they use her for slave labor, or what?

The tent Shmi is kept in, and apparently tortured in, is under guard, so it seems like the sand people anticipated a rescue effort. What's the story there?

Comment: I think they kidnap her and then take her to a camp where she is then tortured and cut to death and by the time her thoughtful son comes to the rescue she has sadly passed away in his very own arms. I still find it a little unrealistic that anakin had to come just in time to see his mother die. The death is perfectly planned so that she dies when he gets there. Anakin then goes out and kills a whole planets worth of innocent people as his anger over the death of his mother creates a hate for not only the men but the innocent women and children.

Comment: The Fremen take her water.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on the Star Wars: Attack of the Clones [*Junior* Novelisation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Episode-II-Novelization/dp/0439139287), it appears that she was initially used as bait (by the Tusken raiding party), then taken to their camp where she was slowly tortured to death. Anakin's dreams *may* be prophetic in nature but it seems more likely that he was simply sensing her pain in real-time. The guards are likely there to discourage any further rescue attempts by the settlers:

**Approx 30 days before her rescue**

> *“It was just before dawn,” he said, his voice hoarse with emotion. “They came out of nowhere. A
>   hunting party of Tusken Raiders —”*
>   ...
>   *Cliegg was still talking.
>   Anakin heard only snatches. “Thirty of us went out after her … I
>   couldn’t ride anymore … This isn’t the way … been gone a month.”
>   Anakin forced his attention back to the present, just as Cliegg
>   finished heavily, “There’s little hope she’s lasted this long.”*

**Approx 20 days before her rescue**

> *“You were dreaming about your mother earlier, weren’t you?” Anakin
>   looked away. “Yes. I left Tatooine so long ago, my memory of her is
>   fading. I don’t want to lose it. And lately I’ve been seeing her in my
>   dreams — vivid dreams. Scary dreams.” His voice became lower and
>   softer. “I worry about her.”*

**Approx 10 days before her rescue**

> *Anakin opened his eyes and looked at her, and she could see in them
>   all the torment he was feeling. “I saw my mother. I saw her as clearly
>   as I see you now.” He swallowed hard. “She’s suffering, Padmé. They’re
>   killing her! She is in pain….”*

Anakin also notes (in his internal monologue) that the Tuskens generally torture captured humans for their own entertainment:

> *Anakin’s mind shut off. Tatooine was controlled by the Hutt criminal
>   organization; it was a haven for smugglers, thieves, and other
>   lowlifes. But even on Tatooine, the Tusken Raiders were considered
>   vicious. They tortured people for fun, and they had his mother? He
>   felt cold. No, Mom, no …*

---

The Official Star Wars: Attack of the Clones [Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_%28novel%29) goes into a little more detail about the actual extent of her torture:

> *Annie was her comfort, her place to hide from the pain the Tuskens
>   had, and were, exacting upon her battered body. **Every day they came in
>   and tortured her a bit more, prodding her with sharp spears or beating
>   her with the blunt shafts and short whips.** It was more than a desire
>   to inflict pain, Shmi realized, though she didn’t speak their croaking
>   language. This was the Tusken way of measuring their enemies, and from
>   the nods and the tone of their voices, she realized that her
>   resilience had impressed them.*

Comment: Very thorough. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann - We aim to please :-)

Comment: “Annie”?! WTF? Isn't it pretty ubiquitously _Ani_, at least in the movies?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet They write out Anakin's nick name in the movies? Like in the subtitles?

Comment: @DCShannon In the subtitles, yeah. I'm guessing they probably get the spelling for the subtitles from the scripts (which I know Richard has available somewhere, 'cause he often quotes them).

Comment: Maybe Ani is now Legends, and Annie is the new Disney version lol

Comment: @thegreatjedi - It's "Annie" in all of the novelisations and all of the scripts. I can't speak for the subtitles, but if they're referring to him as "Ani" then they're typo'd.

Comment: I can't remember the details but I also think it is mentioned a little, from the Tuscan side in the novel 'Kenobi'

Comment: Well, he *is* an orphan now...

Answer (score -2):

I cannot think of any good reason that the Tusken Raiders would kidnap her, torture her, and keep her tied up in a tent for a month.  There is no other example of this behavior by them in any of the other movies.

The only explanation that makes sense to me is that Palpatine set the whole thing up as part of his plan to lead Anakin down the dark path.  When she Shmi dies, Anakin realizes that his Jedi training left him vulnerable.  Since he was unable to save his mother, he becomes open to other paths where the ability to save life is possible.

That being said, the movie does not make this connection for the audience, so this is just a guess.  I think the movie would have been better if it had, as it would have demonstrated some of Palpatine's ruthless scheming and Anakin's manipulation by Palpatine.

As Palpatine's pawns/puppets, the Tusken Raiders all end up slaughtered.  This is a pattern that we see repeated over and over in the films.  Palpatines pawns/puppets are often killed once they have filled their purpose.  That's my take on the Shmi kidnapping/torture.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Fan theories are fun, but this isn't much of an answer to the question asked.

Comment: ^ What he said. Welcome to the site! You should consider taking the tour: this, like most other stack exchange sites, is intended to be a collection of definitive answers, rather than a discussion forum.

Answer (score -3):

Shimi was tortured and killed to lure Anakin and to begin his descent to the dark side. One clear reference was in episode 5 when Anakin (Darth Vader) uses the same tactic to lure his son Luke away by torturing Han. Han says they tortured him and never asked him a question. The Emporer was extremely brilliant in his plot to rule the galaxy. And having the powerful confused boy as his apprentice would more than secure his plan.

Comment: Do you have anything to back up this claim? As it stands, it seems like pure speculation, which does not make for good answers.

Comment: Palpatine intended for Anakin to become his apprentice, yes, but he didn't use the Tuskens - despite their decidedly 16th-century-ish technology, they are among the most feared inhabitants of Tatooine who fear and obey no one, even the Hutt Cartel. If even the Hutts, whom Palpatine could not subjugate, gave the Tuskens a wide berth, what could Palpatine do with them? They are too barbaric to indulge in political intrigue.

Comment: @thegreatjedi while i don't think that palpatine used the tuskens, it would still be possible. just because you can't control them doesn't mean that you can't make a deal with them. you can probably tell them to raid a specific village and take someone prisoner without them objecting. if you want to control someone, you have to tell them the dos and don'ts. and the tuskens probably didn't accept the don'ts...