# How is Anakin’s nickname spelt?

Tags: star-wars, names, the-phantom-menace, attack-of-the-clones, anakin-skywalker

This question was inspired by [Valorum’s answer to the question on what the Tuskens did with Shmi Skywalker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/89382/43655).

In it, he quotes the following from the official [*Attack of the Clones* novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_%28novel%29):

> Annie was her comfort, her place to hide from the pain the Tuskens had, and were, exacting upon her battered body.

Shmi (as it were) uses her usual nickname for her son, Anakin, which is pronounced /ˡani/. In this instance, it is spelt ***Annie***, like the familiar female name/pet form of *Anne*.

Having seen most of the *Star Wars* movies with subtitles (usually either English or Danish)<sup>1</sup> at one point or another, this surprised me, because the only spelling I have ever seen in subtitles is ***Ani***, which I have to admit is at least a bit less gender-bendy than *Annie*. It never even occurred to me, truth be told, that Anakin’s nickname was homophonous with the female name.

Now I don’t know offhand where the subtitlers got their spelling from—movie scripts are frequently made available to subtitlers, but not always, and they may have had other means of enquiry as well—so I cannot say for certain which, if either, is more ‘authentic’.

I’m also not sure if subtitles for the movies or the novelisations should be considered higher canon—they seem about equal to me.

### Is there any canon information (including out-of-universe commentary by directors, George Lucas, etc.) on what the preferred spelling of Anakin Skywalker’s nickname is?

If *Ani*, any info on where the novelisation got *Annie* from? And if *Annie*, any info on where the subtitlers got *Ani* from?

---

<sup>1</sup> I’ve seen one or two with Chinese subtitles, too, but that doesn’t really adduce much—the Chinese form, which I seem to recall is 阿尼, is based on the pronunciation, not the spelling.

Comment: Headcanon: Anakin was never called a girl's name, no matter what the prequels say.

Comment: Looking at various scripts (though not scanned versions), I see that they all seem to say "Annie."

Comment: I believe it was spelled "whiny bi"- err, wait. Which nickname did you want again?

Comment: "Little orphan Annie! Har har har!"

Comment: Given the plethora of sources below, is there anything else you'd like to me address or locate before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum Nope, complete oversight on my part! The last part of the question (where the subtitles got _Ani_) is quite likely unanswerable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's "Annie" in the [Phantom Menace Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html), the [Attack of the Clones script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html) and the [Revenge of the Sith](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html) script.

It's also "Annie" in each of the novels:

**Phantom Menace Junior novelisation**

> *"Storm’s coming on, Annie. You’d better get home quick"*

**Phantom Menace Adult novelisation**

> *The old lady smiled. “The heat’s never been kind to me, you know, Annie.”*

**Attack of the Clones Junior novelisation**

> *"When you say Annie it’s like I’m still a little boy. And I’m not.*”

**Attack of the Clones Adult novelisation**

> *“Oh, Annie, you’ll always be that little boy I knew on Tatooine,” she said*

**Revenge of the Sith Junior novelisation**

> *And then she took a deep breath and went on. “I’m … Annie, I’m
> pregnant.”*

**Revenge of the Sith Adult novelisation**

> *Rising tears burned her eyes, and her lip trembled. “I’m … Annie, I’m pregnant…”*

And in each of the graphic novelisations:

[**Phantom Menace Graphic Novelisation**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Phantom_Menace_Graphic_Novel_Adaptation)

[image]

[**Attack of the Clones Graphic Novelisation**](https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/00-470/Star-Wars-Episode-II----Attack-of-the-Clones-2)

[image]

[**Revenge of the Sith Graphic Novelisation**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_%E2%80%94_Revenge_of_the_Sith)

[image]

As well as the [**Attack of the Clones *Cine-Manga***](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_A_New_Hope_(Cine-Manga))

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any idea where the subtitlers (and Wiki and various other sources) have _Ani_ from?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Nope. It appears to be Ani on the subtitles for all three films.

Comment: Anikin was the original spelling of Luke's father's name. Ani for short.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't help but notice that you didn't specify what language/script you were talking about.

Anakin (and most people in the Galaxy Far Far Away) uses Galactic Basic.

Thus, his preferred spelling of his name is [image: Annie] .

Comment: Good point, actually. I suppose I was thinking mainly out-of-universe (e.g., subtitles), but this is definitely a valid addendum to Richard’s answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's important to remember that novels tend to spell things a bit more phonetically (or in some cases in a familiar way) so that the reader pronounces it correctly. For instance, in the Timothy Zahn EU novels, Luke refers to R2D2 as `R2`, but the novel prefers to spell it `Artoo` ([article with phonetic spelling](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-D2)).

Every spelling I've seen outside of novels or screen plays has his nickname spelled as `Ani` (and that would be in keeping with the spelling of his name, which is typically shortened and not radically changed). [The Star Wars Wikia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) seems to suggest this was in the subtitles of Episodes I and III